# Find finite rings $(R,+,\times)$ such that for every unit $r$, $r-1$ is a unit except $r=1$.

Tags: finite-rings

Let $(R,+,\times)$ be a finite ring. $R^\times$ denotes the set of all invertible elements, i.e., units in $(R,\times)$.

> Find finite rings $(R,+,\times)$ such that for every unit $r\in R^\times\setminus\{1\}$, $r-1$ is a unit.

I know that finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$ are such rings. Then I try to prove that they must be finite field.

My Attempt:

Assume that $r$ and $r-1$ are units. Then there exist $x,y\in R^\times$ such that 
$$rx=xr=1$$
and 
$$(r-1)y=y(r-1)=1.$$
Now we have
$$(r-rx)y=(r-1)y=1=rx$$
and thus
$$(1-x)y=x.$$

I do not know how to contiue...

Comment: It might be useful to keep in mind that every finite integral domain is a field.

Comment: @GerryMyerson How to say that such rings are integral domain? It is obvious if it is for every non-zero element $r$ rather than for every non-identity unit $r$.

Comment: If it's not an integral domain, it has a zero divisor, call it $r$. So $r$ is not a unit, so $r+1$ can't be a unit, so $r+2$ can't be a unit, and so on. Maybe you can make some progress, knowing there have to be all those non-units.

Comment: @GerryMyerson if the characteristic is $p$, then $r+p=r$ for all $r\in R$. So we can only say that if there is one non-unit, then there are at least $p$ non-units.

Comment: Well, applying the hypothesis to the subring generated by $1$, we easily get that the characteristic is prime, so $R$ must be an algebra over $\Bbb F_p$. Playing around with (minimal) polynomials, I guess, it could lead to the desired result, that is, $R$ actually is a field.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, $\ 0\ $ is not a unit but $\ 0+1\ $ is a unit.

Comment: @Wlod, I'm not sure what your point is. We already know that when $r$ is the unit $1$, then $r-1$ is not a unit; we're wondering what happens if for every unit $r$ other than $1$, $r-1$ is a unit.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I guess, I didn't follow the thread of the discussion. Sorry.

Comment: Zhong Xiang Ti, I don't see where did (−) come from? (after words "Now we have").

Comment: @Berci Yes, it is true if the ring is generated by $1$.  But how can I say such rings must be generated by $1$ ?

Comment: @WlodAA Note that $(r-1)y=1$ and $rx=1$. So $(r-rx)y=(r-1)y$ and it follows.

Comment: Zhong Xiang Yi, thank you (blind me, so embarrassing :) ).

Answer (score 3):

Boolean Algebras B are "such rings".

Indeed, they have only one unit, $\ B^x=\{1\}.$

Comment: I guess you mean Boolean rings. This shows the guess in the comments is not true..

Comment: Thank you. (I have a weak connection between the above and below my nose).

Comment: Logically, Boolean Algebras $R=B$ are "such rings". However it is trival where $R^\times\setminus\{1\}=\emptyset$.

Comment: Zhong Xiang Yi, true. It still contributes to a better and complete understanding of the problem (as simple as it is).